# How can I get uwsgi to accept POST request without data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, post, curl, uwsgi

I have a web application that serves post requests, and handles cases when no data or empty data are given. When running the application manually, it behaves properly. But when serving it through uwsgi, a specific case fails, POST requests with no data (empty data works):

```
$ curl -X POST http://www.example.com/search
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ curl -d "" http://www.example.com/search 
[{...}]
```

Is there any uwsgi option I missed that could fix this behavior? How can I get uwsgi to properly forward those requests to my web application?

Comment: check uwsgi/app logs. The WSGI standard (and so uWSGI) has no special case for this condition.

Answer (score 0):

As @roberto stated, it was a problem in my code. I had this piece of code:

When a user does a post query without data, wheezy will try building self.request.form using environ variables like CONTENT_LENGTH, which here doesn't exist and raises an error.  Somehow, the try/except did not work with uwsgi, so I changed:

```
try:
    self.request.form
except:
    self.request.form = {}
    self.request.files = {}
```

As follow:

```
if not self.request.environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', False):
   self.request.form = {}  
   self.request.files = {}
```

And it works fine now